# Android, не могу получить html код страницы

Tags: java, android

Приложение, в котором указывается ссылка в edit1, например http://example.ru
После нажатия кнопки but1 html код по ссылке выдаётся в text1. Это в теории, на практике после нажатия кнопки в text1 ничего не выводится.
По информации от дебаггера дальше определённой строки потом не идёт, вот она: `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con1.getInputStream()));`
Код участка:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button but1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final TextView text1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final EditText edit1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    URL url = null;
                    url = new URL(edit1.getText().toString());
                    URLConnection con1 = url.openConnection();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con1.getInputStream()));
                    String line ="";
                    while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                        text1.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вынести данную операцию в отдельный поток, советую использовать  AsyncTask.
Все сетевые операции в android проводятся в отдельных потоках.

Исходник потока:

```
    class HTMLGet extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
    {
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute()
    {
    //Обновление интерфейса до начала получения html
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
    //HTTP запрос
    return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
    //Обновление интерфейса после получения html
    }
    }
```

Запуск потока:

```
HTMLGet htmlGet=new HTMLGet();
String URL="http://....";
htmlGeg.execute(URL);
```

Не забудьте добавить требуемое разрешение в манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Благодарю за внимание и совет, это работает.