# Правильное кодирование отдельного потока Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Добрый день,

Есть задача получить список строк html в Android приложении. (в PHP это решается простым вызовом filegetcontent() и ни о чем думать не надо :) Прочитал что это можно сделать только создав отдельный поток : [Android, не могу получить html код страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435097/android-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)

Сделал абсолютно отдельными классами:

```
class HTMLGet extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
{
public BufferedReader reader;

@Override
public void onPreExecute()
{
//Обновление интерфейса до начала получения html
}

@Override
public Void doInBackground(String... params)
{
//HTTP запрос
    try{
        URL url = null;
        url = new URL("http://google.com");
        URLConnection con1 = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con1.getInputStream()));
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
return null;
}


@Override
public void onPostExecute(Void result)
{
//Обновление интерфейса после получения html
    try{
        String line ="";
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.printf(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
}
```

И описание mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


public void onmyClick(View view) throws IOException
    {
        HTMLGet htmlGet = new HTMLGet();
        String URL="http://google.com"; //Параметр передаю но пока код его не использует
        htmlGet.execute(URL);


        Toast.makeText(this, "Page connect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            view.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
    }
}
```

Проект отлично компилируется на Eclipse но нужного результата не дает т.е. ничего не выводится :( в связи с этим и вопрос как правильно кодировать отдельный поток, где он должен находится()относительно МайнАктивити, чтобы получить строки html по url... 
и попутно вопрос, который мне подсказали: как правильно передать BufferedReader reader внутри класса HTMLGet а также TextEdit3(из MainActivity) например в класс HTMLGet чтобы туда записался собственно загруженный код html(вместо prinf)...

Comment: У вас поле `HTMLGet.reader` не инициализируется (в `doInBackground` вы создаете локальную переменную с тем же именем), поэтому когда доходит до `onPostExecute` все умирает с NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Решение заключается в правильной манипуляции классом AsyncTask. Конструктор имеет 3-и параметра, каждый из которых может использоваться в одном из трех основных методов. 
Таким образом выполняя какие либо действия в doInBackGround мы должны передать информацию в onPostExecute - это главное. Опционально можно передавать % выполнения задачи в onProgressUpdate ...